# Link to another page with transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a form and when I submit it I want to fade it out. When I load the page the form goes to I want to fade it in. So I actually want to simulate ajax and make it look like the page doesn't redirect.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Fading out is easy, just fade out on submit and hold other actions till this is finished. Fading in might be a problem, afaik the page firsts needs to load until it can perform any Jquery and animations. If you load the page dynamically inside a container then you would just wait till that content is loaded and fade it in when ready.

Comment: Hm okay I suppose the best way then is to just use ajax instead of linking through.

Comment: That would make things easier for sure. I might have a hacky solution for you though: You can overlay a container over each page  so it loads blank, when the page is ready you just fade that container away ;).

Answer (score 1):

Fading out is easy, you just fade out all your content when a user pressed submit and once the animations finishes you load the new page. But fading in a new page is a problem, afaik you need to have the page loaded to perform animations like that. I might be wrong however.

I do have a somewhat hacky solutions for you. You could load each page with a screen filling container, set it's background color to white for example so the screen renders completely white. When the document is ready you just fade that container away with Jquery. This should work the way you want i believe.

*Out of my head so just take it as a guideline, there are many more ways to animate things with css and jquery*

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   //Fade out container div
   $("#overlay").animate({
            visibility: hidden;
        });
});

function onSubmit()
{
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevents the form from submitting.

    $("#overlay").animate({
            visibility: visible;
        },
        {
             complete: function()
             {
                 $("#form").submit();
             }
        }
});
```

**Important!** When a user has java disabled he won't see anything at all.

Comment: What if I would use display:none in the body of the next page instead?

Comment: Yeah that should work too, default it by display:none and upon ready show it.

Comment: @SinanSamet Had any luck with it?